# How to execute for all possible combinations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got this code below that generates a random 5-character code. For example `AU330`, `UEEHB`, `2EH8D` `HJ1LM`.

```js
function makeid(length) {
   var result           = ''
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
   }
   return result
}

alert(makeid(5));
```

What I want to do is check each possible code for `U330` and for each code that contains it, log it to console.

**Expected Output:**

AU330

BU330

CU330

DU330

...

Comment: We can see your code that generates a random code, but where's your attempt at seeing if it contains `U330`? Seems like a basic one-liner

Comment: Also, why to check for all combinations, if your are interested in 72 well-known combinations? (out of 11.9M)

Comment: Have you tried String.prototype.indexOf();

Comment: There are 60,466,176 possible combinations, `36^5`.  You can't get _all_ of them using a random number generator.  You would have to construct each one.  In either case, you don't really want to do that since really you are only looking for either `_U330` or `U330_`.

Comment: @nurdyguy I plan on checking for something later on like checking for AU330_D537 and BU330_D537 etc. the code will always end in _D537.

Comment: Checking if a random string contains `...U330...` is fairly easy, just use `str.includes("U330")` for example.  Constructing all possible permutations is more complex.  Is there really a reason why you _need_ to generate all possible permutations?

Comment: @nurdyguy trying to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222643/can-you-download-images-from-a-specific-domain-for-each-page-ending-in-a-string

Comment: Yeah, you are going to need to generate every single possibility then.  First, just try doing that, generating all possible permutations of 5-digits.

Comment: @nurdyguy how, might I ask?

Comment: There's more than one way to do it but none are trivial.  The most efficient method I've found is by using Lehmer Codes to generate the specific permutation, then you just loop through.  Here is a site that may point you in the right direction.  https://2ality.com/2013/03/permutations.html

Comment: Also note: Best way to approach a "generate all" is to pick a specific order.  For example, the first one is `aaaaa` then `aaaab` then `aaaac` then ...  then `aaaa9` then `aaaba` ...  Now think about how you would code up creating that sequence.  This is not super hard but also not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply search for a substring with indexOf() function or check for the exact string with regular expressions.

```
var input = "AU330";

console.log(input.indexOf("U330") !== -1); //Indexof
console.log(/[A-Z0-9]U330/.test(input)); //Regex
```